Bulk assign products to new Magento Website -> Copy from Specific Storeview
I have a multi-website setup in my Magento.
Here i want assign all products from a not-default storeview (german) to my new website (austria)
When assigning one products (Products -> Choose product -> "Assign to website": I'm offered the possibility to choose what website i want to copy the data from.
(This is convenient - but unfortunately this functionality is not offered when i want to "mass edit")
If i do it by "Mass action" = it will only copy from "default store view" -> Which i can't use for anything.
So basically my question is:
How can most easily copy all my product from a specific website/storeview to a new website/storeview from a not-default website/storeview?

The most optimal way to achieve this is to create a script that will copy all the specific website/store view product data and re-save the products.
Another workaround I think of it is to set the specific store as the default one for the time being and once copying is done, revert and change the default store again. - However, I have not tested this personally so I suggest taking a Database backup first before performing this.
Another way is, to export the products, change the website and store ID in the sheet, and re-import the same.
